# Recurrence and transience of cocycle over a dynamical system

Tags: ergodic-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $T$ a homeomorphism on $X$ and $\mu$ a $T$-invariant probability measure. Let $\phi:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $\phi_n(x)=\phi(x)+\cdots+\phi(T^{n-1}x)$ be the induced cocycle.

A point $x\in X$ is said to be $\phi$-transient if $|\phi_n(x)|\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Otherwise $x$ is said to be $\phi$-recurrent. The following two propositions strengthen the $\phi$-recurrence property:

(1). For $\mu$-a.e. $\phi$-recurrent point $x$, $\displaystyle \liminf_{n\to\infty}|\phi_{n}(x)|=0$.

(2). Assume $(T,\mu)$ is ergodic and $\int\phi d\mu=0$. Then $\mu$-a.e. point $x$ is $\phi$-recurrent. In particular $\displaystyle \liminf_{n\to\infty}|\phi_{n}(x)|=0$ $\mu$-a.e. $x$.

How to prove these two properties?

Comment: What is $f$? Is this $T$? 

Comment: Classical Gottschalk-Hedlund's Theorem (see Theorem 2.9.4 in Katok-Hasselblatt) tells you that if you have a recurrent point then your cocycle is a coboundary: $\phi_n(x)=u(T^n(x))-u(x)$, with $u$ continuous function on $X$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yes. This is a typo. @Ian I revised my question. I want to know how to prove these two propositions.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but how is the inequality $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int \phi_n d\mu \geq \int \liminf_{n \to \infty}\phi_n d\mu$ justified? Fatou's lemma does not work here, for example, because the functions $\phi_n$ might fail to be uniformly bounded below. 

Comment: @Ian Oops, that is a mistake. Usually $\phi_n(x)$ is unbounded for a.e. $x$ unless $\phi$ is a coboundary. 

Comment: @Pengfei Unless I am missing something, none of your three sets $X_r$, $X_+$ and $X_-$ is invariant under T.

Comment: @V.Delecroix You are right. I have deleted that part (after more than ten years).

Comment: @MicheleTriestino Here the definition of a point being recurrent is slightly weaker: it allows that $|\phi_n(x)|$ oscillates between 0 and $\infty$. As your comment has suggested, both properties (1) and (2) hold trivially for cobundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure what the question is, but the following result might be a helpful starting point:

Theorem (Giles Atkinson, 1976): Let $T$ be an ergodic invertible measure-preserving transformation of a probability space $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and let $\phi \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable. Then the following statements are equivalent:

1. $\int \phi\,d\mu=0$
2. For all $A \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\mu(A)>0$, and all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a nonzero integer $n$ such that $\mu\left(A \cap T^{-n}A \cap \{x \colon |\phi_n(x)|<\varepsilon\}\right)>0$.

Here we define $\phi_n(x)=0$ if $n=0$ and $\phi_n(x)=\phi_{-n}(T^nx)$ if $n$ is negative. Note that by taking $A=X$ and considering a sequence of values of $\varepsilon$ tending to zero we obtain $\liminf_{|n|\to \infty} \phi_n(x)=0$ a.e.

This falls slightly short of proving the statement (2) in the original post since *a priori* the sequence of integers $n$ along which convergenence to zero takes place might not take infinitely many positive values. I am fairly sure that the sequence can be taken so as to tend to $+\infty$ (indeed it is not unusual to see Atkinson's theorem cited in that form) but Atkinson's original paper unfortunately does not include that statement. I seem to remember that Aaronson's book on infinite ergodic theory includes a proof and so might shed light on this question, but I appear to have mislaid my copy.

(That a.e. $x \in X$ is recurrent in the topological sense (when $X$ is a compact metric space) when $\mu$ is an invariant Borel probability measure is a standard result: see for example Proposition 4.1.18 in Katok and Hasselblatt.)